# Max query returning null object with sequelise.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am having an issue with `sequelise.js`'s `max` query functionality where the "success" object being returned is `null` despite the logged query being as expected (and working against the database being targeted).

Without further ado here is the codez;

```
LunaEventDomain
        .max("date", {where : { "luna_event_location_id": lunaLocationId }})
        .success(function(max) {
            console.log("Max object, %s", max);
            console.log("Max object is date? [%s]", typeof max == Date);
            var result;
            if (max == null) {
                result = false;
            } else {
                result = checkHasRecordsAfter(daysInAdvance, max);
            }
            return result;
        })
        .error(function(error) {
            console.log("Encountered an error from max query, [%s]", error);
        });
```

*Snippet 1:* The max query code.

The log notes;

```
Executing (default): SELECT max(`date`) as `max` FROM `luna_event` WHERE `luna_event`.`luna_event_location_id`='1';
Max object, null
Max object is date? [false]
```

*Snippet 2:* The resulting log.

The `LunaEventDomain` table has (MySQL) schema;

```
id                      int(11)
event_type              enum('LOW_WATER', 'HIGH_WATER', 'MOONRISE', 'MOONSET')
date                    datetime
height                  decimal(10,3)
luna_event_location_id  int(11)
```

When I execute the logged query against the target database I retrieve an appropriate response. What am I doing wrong? I would like the max result to be delivered as part of the `success(function(max) { ... })` callback.

Comment: Looks like this is me not understanding sequelisejs#sync whuch clears down the db between server restarts. The max query returns as expected after the 2nd request!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is me not understanding `sequelisejs#sync` which clears down the db between server restarts. The max query returns as expected after the 2nd request!